# How to pass the parameters using multidimensional array in webservice

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, soap

How can I pass the parameters in web service using this request:

POST /webservice/User.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://sample.com/UpdateUserBatch"

```
<UpdateUserBatch xmlns="http://sample.com/">
  <auth>
    <Username>string</Username>
    <Password>string</Password>
  </auth>
  <request>
    <CreateIfNotExist>boolean</CreateIfNotExist>
    <UpdateIfExists>boolean</UpdateIfExists>
    <Users>
      <UserProfile>
        <UserID>string</UserID>
        <BusinessID>string</BusinessID>
        <ExternalID>string</ExternalID>
        <Username>string</Username>
        <Password>string</Password>
        <UpdateDate>dateTime</UpdateDate>
      </UserProfile>
      <UserProfile>
        <UserID>string</UserID>
        <BusinessID>string</BusinessID>
        <ExternalID>string</ExternalID>
        <Username>string</Username>
        <Password>string</Password>
        <UpdateDate>dateTime</UpdateDate>
      </UserProfile>
    </Users>
  </request>
</UpdateUserBatch>
```

I'd like to import data using the that web service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with `POST` requests, but in `GET` requests you usually use square bracket notation for multi-dimension arrays. For example:

`http://api.example.com/object/?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz`

This would be assembled, API side, like thus:

```
'foo' => array(
    0 => 'bar',
    1 => 'baz'
);
```

Of course, you could use indexed arrays as well as numerical arrays.

Comment: thank you for your reply but it seems doesn't work. I got an error "Service Unavailable".

Comment: That's not a problem with your implementation, but the actual service you're sending your request to.